# Reading JPEG Stream over socket gives Null characters

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream, fileinputstream

I am reading a `.jpg` file over `InputStream` using this code but I am receiving **NULNUL...n** stream after some text. Ii am reading this file [link to file](http://www.filetolink.com/655a0bb11b) and link of file that I received , link is [Written File link](http://www.filetolink.com/0b1f6453c8).

```
    while ((ret = input.read(imageCharArray)) != -1) {
    packet.append(new String(imageCharArray, 0, ret));

    totRead += ret;
            imageCharArray = new char[4096];
       }


   file = new File(
     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
       + "/FileName_/"
       + m_httpParser.filename + ".jpg");
   PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
   // outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);  //also Used FileoutputStream for writting
   // outputStream.write(packet.toString().getBytes());//
   // ,
   printWriter.write(packet.toString());
   // outputStream.close();
   printWriter.close();
 }
```

I have also tried `FileoutputStream` but hardlucj for this too as commented in my code.

**Edit** 
 I have used this also. I have a content length field upto which i am reading and writing

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
int totalReadLength = 0;

// read untill we have bytes
while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1
        && contentLength >= (totalReadLength)) {

    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
    totalReadLength += read;
    System.out.println(" read size ======= "
            + read + " totalReadLength = "
            + totalReadLength);

}
```

Comment: Your reading link is not working.

Comment: it depands of what typ of data u are sending if u are sending bytes thn u ll b able to recieve bytes other side show ur socketserver code

Comment: @raj Its JPEG data other side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String is not a container for binary data, and PrintWriter isn't a way to write it. Get rid of all, *all,* the conversions between bytes and String and *vice versa,* and just transfer the bytes with input and output streams:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

If you need to constrain the number of bytes read from the input, you have to do that *before* calling read(), and you also have to constrain the read() correctly:

```
while (total < length && (count = in.read(buffer, 0, length-total > buffer.length ? buffer.length: (int)(length-total))) > 0)
{
    total += count;
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: Beat me too it. I would also recommend the Apache IOUtil library for this sort of thing: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

Comment: I have used this but its again giving me corrupted jpeg file.

Comment: @KanakSony Then you must have misused it. This is the basis of every copy operation I have ever programmed for about forty-three years, including 17 years in Java. Post your current code. Edit it into your question.

Comment: You haven't used it at all. The code you've now posted, in comments, bears precisely zero relationship to what I've suggested here.

Comment: @EJP In comments which i have added already which was one of soln i have used and now code i have added is after Edit mark. I'll use ur way for limiting it upto content length. Is it ri8 way to write for JPEG photo stream?.

Comment: @EJP Thanks Man.. You are a champ. Actually I was doing something wrong which I corrected and the issue solved. :)

Comment: @KanakSony Actually you weren't using the code I posted, let's face it.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it in my Nexus4 and it's working for me. Here is the snippet of code what I tried :

```
public void saveImage(String urlPath)throws Exception{ 
        String fileName = "kumar.jpg";
        File folder = new File("/sdcard/MyImages/");
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        folder.mkdirs();


        final File output = new File(folder,
                fileName);
        if (output.exists()) {
            output.delete();
        }

        InputStream stream = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
//          InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            byte[] fileData = new byte[url.openConnection().getContentLength()];
             for (int x = 0; x < fileData.length; x++) { // fill byte array with bytes from the data input stream
                    fileData[x] = dis.readByte();

                }
             dis.close();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
            fos.write(fileData);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Just Call the above function in a background thread and pass your url. It'll work for sure. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: trying this.. will let u know.

Comment: Sure, Please go ahead :)

Answer (score -1):

You can check below code.

```
 destinationFile = new File(
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
   + "/FileName_/"
   + m_httpParser.filename + ".jpg");

BufferedOutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationFile));
byte byt[] = new byte[1024];
int i;
for (long l = 0L; (i = input.read(byt)) != -1; l += i ) {
   buffer.write(byt, 0, i);
}
buffer.close();
```

Comment: it is indicate that your file will not exceed some long limit.

Comment: It doesn't do that. It's a write-only variable that starts at zero, is incremented, and is never read anywhere in your code. If it's meant to implement a total size limit, it doesn't do that either, because you have to constrain the read size on the last read.

Comment: Thanks.. For giving me suggestion.